# java, why these error? --maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0

Tags: java, maven, javac, opendaylight

I'm walking through the following opendaylight guide:
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html#

there are errors during compilation:

```
[ERROR] ...Odl-testProvider.java:[14,17] '{' expected
[ERROR] ...Odl-testProvider.java:[21,15] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] ...Odl-testProvider.java:[21,16] invalid method declaration; return type required
```

Odl-testProvider.java:

```
/*
* Copyright © 2017 Copyright(c) Yoyodyne, Inc. and others.  All rights reserved.
*
* This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
* terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 which accompanies this distribution,
* and is available at http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
*/
package org.opendaylight.solaroi.impl;

import org.opendaylight.controller.md.sal.binding.api.DataBroker;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Odl-testProvider //line 14
{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Odl-testProvider.class);

private final DataBroker dataBroker;

public Odl-testProvider(final DataBroker dataBroker) //line 21
{
    this.dataBroker = dataBroker;
}

/**
 * Method called when the blueprint container is created.
 */
public void init() 
{
    LOG.info("Odl-testProvider Session Initiated");
}

/**
 * Method called when the blueprint container is destroyed.
 */
public void close() 
{
    LOG.info("Odl-testProvider Closed");
}
}
```

compiler info:

> goal: maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile(default-compile)
>   compiler 'javac', source = 1.8, target = 1.8

Comment: "Odl-testProvider" is not a valid identifier.  It is 2 identifiers with a minus symbol ... which will confuse any compiler.   In short: this is a syntax error due to **typo**.

Comment: Indeed, a compilation error has nothing to do with the maven compiler plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take a look at the allowed characters for Java class names. `-` is not allowed. Take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Comment: You seem to be used the Oxygen release of OpenDaylight.  Just wanted to let you know that you perhaps would like to use the latest version called Fluorine which we just released; see https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html  but note that the `archetypeGroupId` changed from `org.opendaylight.controller` to `org.opendaylight.archetypes`.